# embedding one function another Jython

Tags: function, jython

The goal of the assignment is to have the two functions work together, or i.e. have setPixeltoBlack being called into setPicturetoblack.

The error is quite obvious:

```
The error was:'javainstance' object has no attribute '__call__'
Attribute not found.
You are trying to access a part of the object that doesn't exist.
Please check line 10 of /Users/tobiasdouglas/test3
```

The main issue: How does one ask the computer to check that two variables (xpos, ypos) exist?
I wrote the pseduocode out (shown with #) of what is desired.

Thanks.

```
import random
file=pickAFile()
picture=makePicture(file)
show(picture)
xpos = input("Enternumber")
ypos = input("Enternumber")

def setPixelToBlack(getPixel):
#if xpos and ypos = known
  setColor=(getPixel(picture,xpos,ypos),black)
#else
  #setcolor=(getPixels(picture), black)
  explore(picture)
  return

def setPictureToBlack(picture):
  for p in getPixels(picture):
    setPixelToBlack(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use specal value `None` and check if variable is `None` with `is None` or `is not None`.

```
xpos = None
ypos = None

// some code that may set xpos or ypos

def setPixelToBlack(getPixel):
    if xpos is not None and ypos is not None:
        setColor=(getPixel(picture,xpos,ypos),black)
    // ...
```

Also in your code `xpos` and `ypos` are global variables. You can read them in functions, but to change its values you will need to use `global xpos, ypos` statement.